# convert image coordinates to matrix index

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

Im trying to remove blobs from a image (Python3). The problem is that im getting the position of the blobs in cartesian coordinates. My intention is to get the position of the blobs in matrix indexes so i can acess them and remove them (making them equal to zero).

here is my code:

```
for i in range(1, 2):

    name                = str(i) + ".jpg"
    nameBW              = str(i) + "_bw.jpg"
    img                 = cv2.imread(name,0) #zero -> abre em grayscale
    #threshold manual
    retval, threshold_manual    = cv2.threshold(img, 50, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    #threshold adaptativo
    threshold_adaptativo        = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
    # medianblur por cima do threshold adaptativo
    median                      = cv2.medianBlur(threshold_adaptativo,5)
    #2ª dose de medianBlur
    median2                     = cv2.medianBlur(median,1)


    # Setup SimpleBlobDetector parameters.
    params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()

    # Change thresholds
    params.minThreshold = 1
    params.maxThreshold = 2000
    # Filter by Area.
    params.filterByArea = True
    params.minArea = 0.1
    # Filter by Circularity
    params.filterByCircularity = False
    params.minCircularity = 0.1
    # Filter by Inertia
    # params.filterByInertia = True
    # params.minInertiaRatio = 0.001

    detector                = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)
    keypoints               = detector.detect(median2)
    im_with_keypoints       = cv2.drawKeypoints(median2, keypoints, np.array([]), (0,0,255), cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)

    for j in range(1, len(keypoints)):
        x = keypoints[j].pt[0] #i is the index of the blob you want to get the position
        y = keypoints[j].pt[1]
        median2[x, y] = 0
```

here is the image i want to clean:
[image]

keypoints is what is coming in cartesian coordinates. What i want is to convert it to matrix indexes so i can access the same indexes on the image median2 and then remove the blobs.

Comment: Can you please fix the indentation? It is very difficult to read, and I don't want to change the behavior of your code by indenting at the wrong point.

Comment: of course, 1 sec

Comment: You can remove them making them equal to zero? I don't understand

Comment: Anyway, what do you mean to change them from cartesian coordinates to a matrix? Cartesian coordinates are already stored in a matrix, I suppose. Or what you want to do is merge the x list with the y list into a 2xn matrix?

Comment: Perhaps my logic is also wrong. I'm coming from Matlab where I'm used to do it this way. Changing values on the image matrix has a direct effect on the image, right?

Comment: Ahhh all right, I understand now.

Comment: If the image is a matrix with the pixel colour, then yes, it should do the trick. Is your code not working? And if not, why? What do you get?

Comment: what i want is to access the matrix on the position of the blob and eliminate it. Should i not be imagining images as matrices?

Comment: For what I read in your code, that should work. Why is it not working?

Comment: : )     well, keypoints, instead of giving me the index of the matrix where the blob is, is giving me the (x,y) (cartesian) coordinates of the blob

Answer (score 1):

### (1) Syntax error:

Your code:

```
for j in range(1, len(keypoints)):
    x = keypoints[j].pt[0] #i is the index of the blob you want to get the position
    y = keypoints[j].pt[1]
    median2[x, y] = 0
```

As we know, keypoints are float, while the index should be int; and we index the image by [rows, cols], that is [y,x].

modified：

```
for kpt in keypoints:
    x = int(pt[0])     # change float to int 
    y = int(pt[1])
    median2[y, x] = 0  # index in [row,col] order, that is (y,x)
```

### (2) logic error

You cann't remove small regions by set the blob keypoints to zeros.

Comment: thank you for your answer. ive been looking online and i cant seem to find a way to effectively removing the blobs. any suggestions? i uploaded the image i want to clean